# Python web-scraping output

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to make a script that prints the links to results in bing search to the console. The problem is that when I run the script there is no output. I believe the website thinks I am a bot?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search = input("search for:")
params = {"q": "search"}
r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find("ol", {"id": "b_results"})
links = results.find_all("Li", {"class": "b_algo"})

for item in links:
    item_text = item.find("a").text
    item_href = item.find("a").attrs["href"]

    if item_text and item_href:
        print(item_text)
        print(item_href)
```

Comment: could ```find_all``` be case-sensitive?  i.e. ```Li``` vs. ```li```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the search variable instead of "search". You also have a typo in your script: `li` is lower case.

Change these lines:

```
params = {"q": "search"}
.......
links = results.find_all("Li", {"class": "b_algo"})
```

To this:

```
params = {"q": search}
........
links = results.find_all("li", {"class": "b_algo"})
```

Note that some queries don't return anything. "crossword" has results, but "peanut" does not. The result page structure may be different based on the query.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in this code -

1. Search is a variable name, so it should not be used with quotes. Change it to below

`params = {"q": search}`

2. When you include variable name inside quotes while fetching link, it becomes a static link. For dynamic link you should do it as below -

`r = requests.get("http://www.bing.com/"+search, params=params)`

After making these 2 changes, if you still do not get any output , check if you are using correct tag in results variable.